# AS3 CheckBox Wont Work

Tags: actionscript-3, checkbox

Hey all, basically i have an empty AS3 fla file with just the following code:

```
import fl.controls.CheckBox;

var cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.label = "Beets";
cb1.y = 10;
addChild(cb1);
```

But when i run it, i keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fl.controls::CheckBox/drawLayout()
    at fl.controls::LabelButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

What am i doing wrong? :S

Comment: None of the code you have posted should throw that error.  Do you have a custom skin for this checkbox?  It could be some element that is missing from the skin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hey all, basically i have an empty AS3 fla file with just the following code:

Did you add to your library a checkbox component?